# Проверка текста Delphi

Tags: delphi

Привет всем) 
На форме есть memo1,в ней куча md5 хешей,и есть edit1,в него я вписую новый md5 хэш,надо проверить ли есть такой хешь в memo1(в мемо больше 100 хешей).

Comment: @Влад Андреев, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Сначала я просто с помощью if memo.Text := 'hash',а строк много ( 
Просто не пойму как выполнить это

Comment: Вот так:

    if Memo1.Lines.IndexOf(str)<0 then
      ShowMessage('Нету такого хэша')
    else
      ShowMessage('Уже есть такой');

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, краткость сестра таланта.  

----  

А компилятор одинаково сформирует такой код "if Memo1.Lines.IndexOf(str)<0 then" и пробегание всех строк в цикле?

Comment: одинаково, конечно. IndexOf из TStrings идет. Для другого поиска, где нужно в больших объемах искать, другими вариантами пользуются hashedstringlist и т.д. memo - это я так понял на коленке и для теста тут используется...

Comment: еще предложу вариант отсортировать хеши, и бинарным поиском воспользоваться.

Answer (score 4):

вы неправильно делаете. memo.Text берет ВЕСЬ текст, который хранится в мемо, поэтому вам надо делать не жесткое сравнение с вашим хэшем, а поиск в строке. Для этого гуглим функции POS или AnsiPos.

Или второй способ: пролистываете каждую строку (memo.lines) и устраиваете сравнение или опять же поиск в строке.

---

*код не привожу, ибо согласно правилам форума, надо что-то сделать самому ;)*

Comment: Сейчас,попробую )

Comment: @Влад Андреев в цикле сравниваешь каждую строку с заданным хэшем

Comment: Не получилось( Все время ShowMessage('Нету такого хэша') выводило

Comment: @Влад Андреев, покажите ваш код

Comment: if mmo1.Lines.IndexOf(md5hash)>0 then
  ShowMessage('нет')
else
  ShowMessage('да')

Comment: Нашел выход : if Pos(md5scnfile,mmo1.Lines)>0 then  =) Спасибо всем

Comment: @Влад Андреев `Pos(md5scnfile,mmo1.Lines)>0` не скомпилируется, не вводите людей в заблуждение. И условие выше `indexOf>0` будет *истинным* хэш найден в строках, в какой-либо кроме первой. Не за что, да.